# JAXB Annotations - Mapping interfaces and @XmlElementWrapper

Tags: interface, annotations, jaxb

I am having trouble with JAXB annotations for a field that is a list whose generified type is an interface.  When I have it declared such as:

```
@XmlAnyElement
private List<Animal> animals;
```

Every thing works correctly. But when I add a wrapper element, such as:

```
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlAnyElement
private List<Animal> animals;
```

I find that the Java object marshals correctly, but when I unmarshal the document created by marshaling, my list is empty. I have posted below the code to demonstrate this problem.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? I have tried it with version 2.1.12 and 2.2-ea with the same result.

I am working through the example for mapping interfaces with annotations located here:
https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html

```
@XmlRootElement
class Zoo {

  @XmlElementWrapper
  @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
  private List<Animal> animals;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
    zoo.animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    zoo.animals.add(new Dog());
    zoo.animals.add(new Cat());

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Zoo.class, Dog.class, Cat.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    marshaller.marshal(zoo, os);

    System.out.println(os.toString());

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Zoo unmarshalledZoo = (Zoo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()));

    if (unmarshalledZoo.animals == null) {
      System.out.println("animals was null");
    } else if (unmarshalledZoo.animals.size() == 2) {
      System.out.println("it worked");
    } else {
      System.out.println("failed!");
    }
  }

  public interface Animal {}

  @XmlRootElement
  public static class Dog implements Animal {}

  @XmlRootElement
  public static class Cat implements Animal {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-669) that was fixed in JAXB 2.1.13. Update your libraries or use JDK 1.7 or later and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 8):

Should use
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(type=Dog.class),
        @XmlElementRef(type=Cat.class)})
    private List animals;

or use 
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true) only, and add Dog.class, Cat.class to JaxbContext

Answer (score 0):

When I run your test program with jdk1.6.0_20 it appears to work and I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<zoo><animals><dog/><cat/></animals></zoo>
it worked
```

Comment: I'm used the version of JAXB 2.1 included with jdk1.6.0_20.  You can also try your example with MOXy JAXB (I'm the tech lead).  We fixed a bug related to your question, you will need to use today's (Nov 4) or later EclipeseLink 2.2.0 nightly download:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your annotations in your accessories? I also had this problem with @XmlElementWrapper before but i got it solved by putting the annotating my getter instead of annotating the field declaration.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your test program with jdk1.6.0_20 it does not work, however once I changed annotation for the list from `@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)` to `@XmlElementRefs({ @XmlElementRef(type=Dog.class), @XmlElementRef(type=Cat.class)})` then it works. It does not matter that `Dog.class` and `Cat.class` are added to JAXBContext or not.